# A pendulum with an hollow bob full of flowing sand

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

### THE PROBLEM

Consider a pendulum with an hollow spheric bob of negligible weight filled with 1.1 kg of fine sand and hanging from an inextensible wire of negligible mass and $l= 30 m$ long. At the point which is diametrically opposite to the point where it is hung to the wire, the sphere has a small hole from which the sand can come out with a constant flow of 1 g/s.

In the rest position the hole is at a distance $h = 1 m$ from the
horizontal floor. At time $t = 0$ the sphere is placed at a distance $d = 30 cm$ from its rest position, the
hole is opened and the sphere is let go (see the drawing for a better understanding).

Neglecting any friction and referring to a Cartesian axis that runs along the floor in the direction of
the motion of the sphere and whose origin is at the point closest to the rest position of the sphere, compute:

1. the position where the sand falls as a function of the time $t$;
2. the maximum distance at which the sand is deposited;
3. the points where the greatest amount of sand is accumulated;
4. the distribution of the mass of sand on the floor.

Assume that the sand remains exactly at the point where it touches the floor.

**HINT** Some useful trigonometric formulas:
$$cos(arctan(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\qquad\qquad \sin(arctan(x))=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

[image]

### (WORKING ON) THE SOLUTION

I suppose that the first thing to notice is that the little-angle approximation can be used since the starting angle $\vartheta_{\text{MAX}}$ (at $t=0$) is easily computed as
$$\vartheta_{\text{MAX}}=arcsin(d/l)=arcsin(0.01)\simeq 0.01000017$$ 
and it's very small. Hence $sin(\vartheta)$ can be approximated with $\vartheta$ and $cos(\vartheta)$ with $1$.

In this approximation, it is well known that the pendulum period is
$$T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{l^*}{g}}$$
Now, strictly speaking, $l^*$ should be the distance between the point in which the wire is hung and the center of mass of the bob. At $t=0$ this means $l^* = l+R$, where $R$ is the radius of the hollow sphere. With the sand flowing away, the center of mass will shift downwards, increasing $l^*$ and hence increasing the time period only to be back at its initial position $l+R$ when there's no sand left inside the bob.

However, since the problem does not give the value for $R$, I assumed that a point-like approximation for the bob could be used, hence using $l^* = l$ regardless of how much sand is left inside the sphere.

I guessed this is what who wrote the problem was asking for since the period so computed is $T \simeq 11s$: a number matching too well the $1.1 g/s$ of the constant flow of sand to be a coincidence (giving the sphere emptied in $100$ periods).

Assuming all of the above is right, I went on to write the equations of motion for the flowing sand:
  \begin{array}{ll}
        x(t) &= x_s + v_x t = l\,sin(\vartheta(t)) + l \dot{\vartheta(t)} t \simeq l\,\vartheta(t) + l \dot{\vartheta(t)} t\\
        y(t) &= y_s + v_y t - \frac{g}{2}t^2= h + l(1-cos(\vartheta)) + l \dot{\vartheta(t)} sin(\vartheta(t)) t - \frac{g}{2}t^2 \simeq h + l \dot{\vartheta(t)} \vartheta(t) t - \frac{g}{2}t^2
        \end{array}

[image]

Then I'd like to set $y(t)=0$ in order to solve for $t$ and substitute inside the equation for $x(t)$...but I don't know how to proceed. Plus, how should the given HINT be useful?

Any help to solve this would be extremely appreciated!

### EDIT (why this is not a duplicate)

This question is not a duplicate because I'm not asking of how the period of pendulum varies with the flowing of the sand but, assuming it does not vary (an approximation), I'm asking about the position where the sand falls as a function of the time $t$; the maximum distance at which the sand is deposited; the points where the greatest amount of sand is accumulated; the distribution of the mass of sand on the floor.

Comment: My answer in the linked question basically says, "It's really hard". You can make some approximations to make it easier, but I suspect the full solution is not analytic.

Comment: There's more to this problem than "just" the varying mass. And again, what if we can neglect the varying mass, supposing the sand is somehow always placed around the center of the sphere or otherwise that the sphere is small enough (point-like approximation)? Are my equations right under this assumption? If so, why the HINT should be useful? And, in general, how to proceed?

Comment: Obviously, thank you very much @Kyle Kanos :)